# Is it possible to set an init-only explicit-implemented property?

Tags: c#, interface, properties, initialization

Let's say we have a class, which must have only one parameterless constructor. The class also define a init-only setter property.

```
class MyClass
{
    public int MyProp { get; init; }
}
```

Since C# 9, we can set that property only at construction time:

```
MyClass c = new()
{
    MyProp = 123,
};
```

So far, so good.

Now, let's suppose that the property is required by an interface, and we need to implement explicitly that interface:

```
interface IFoo
{
    int MyProp { get; init; }
}

class MyClass : IFoo
{
    private int _myProp;

    int IFoo.MyProp
    {
        get => _myProp;
        init => _myProp = value;
    }
}
```

However, that won't compile:

```
MyClass c = new()
{
    MyProp = 123,
};
```

Also, I have no idea about any possible syntax.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation):

> An explicit interface implementation doesn't have an access modifier since **it isn't accessible as a member of the type it's defined in**. Instead, it's only accessible when called through an instance of the interface.

To make your instantiation possible, you therefore need to implement the property as a non-explicit-implementation of the interface as well:

```cs
class MyClass : IFoo
{
    private int _myProp;

    int IFoo.MyProp
    {
        get => MyProp;
        init => MyProp = value;
    }

    public int MyProp
    {
        get => _myProp;
        init => _myProp = value;
    }
}
```

Of course, if you don't want `IFoo.MyProp` to use the non-explicit implementation as a "backing property" you can change that.

Comment: Could set it from the ctor also, although that kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Xerillio thanks, but your solution is basically the first part of my post.

Comment: @MarioVernari but that's how C# works. You cannot avoid the non-explicit interface implementation if you want to access it outside the context of the interface.

Comment: @Xerillio nothing to blame to your reference to the docs. That's okay, and I mean the answer to my question is "no". However, your snippet is a non-solution to me, because that's the starting point of my question. I wanted to avoid the non-explicit implementation, and the interface was a trick to make more difficult the access to the property for a distracted user.

Comment: @Xerillio I'll accept your answer for the effort you made, but to me it should be limited to the docs reference. The second part is wrong.